# AngularJS ng-csv file downloading sometimes only

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular ng-csv directive to download the csv file. Sometimes it is not downloading the file.

The code is as below

```
<button ng-csv="csvdata" filename="{{ filetitle }}.csv">Download CSV</button>
```

The data in the file may huge and When it is not downloading it is not displaying any errors in console.

I checked by putting `console.log` in library as well all working fine but not downloading file. It is using Blob to download the files. Is there limitation for the Blob for downloading or anyone can tell how to debug this kind of issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i've downloaded hundred of MBs from Blob URLs...

Comment: Yes. Some times i am getting this issues for small datasets also. Iam not getting why this happens